# Equations or areas where $(AA^T)^x$ or $(A^TA)^x$ are used as applications

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, applications

Let $A$ be square or rectangular and $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Can you point me to equations/areas out there where $(AA^T)^x$ or $(A^TA)^x$ or their eigenvalues are used as applications? e.g. we find them in the polar decomposition when $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

I'm particular about cases when $x\ne 0, \frac{1}{2}, 1$. Thanks in advance.

$A$ may also be taken to be complex i.e. $(AA^*)^x$ or $(A^*A)^x$.

Comment: what does $A^x$ mean for real $x$?

Comment: Would you be willing to use a formula in terms of the eigenvalues of $A^TA$?  There's also a formula using a power series.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom. Yes, I will consider their eigenvalues too. I have edited the post to include that $A$ can also be rectangular.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, please expantiate on the formula using a power series, and that which considers the eigenvalues. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'll stick to the real case, but the situation for complex matrices is similar.

$A^TA$ is a symmetric and positive semidefinite matrix.
By the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Finite-dimensional_case), there exists an orthogonal $U$ such that $U^T(A^TA)U$ is diagonal, that is
$$
U^T(A^TA)U = D = \pmatrix{\lambda_1 \\ & \ddots \\ && \lambda_n}
$$
where the $\lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ (i.e. the singular values of $A$). Because $A^TA$ is positive semidefinite, the eigenvalues $\lambda_k$ are non-negative, that is $\lambda_k \geq 0$ for all $k$.

We may compute
$$
(A^TA)^x = [U D U^T]^x = UD^x U^T = U \pmatrix{\lambda_1^x \\ & \ddots \\ && \lambda_n^x}U^T
$$
Because $\lambda_k\geq 0$ for all $k$, $\lambda_k^x$ makes sense for all $x > 0$.  If we also know that $A^TA$ is invertible (i.e. that $A$ has full column rank), then we have $\lambda_k > 0$ which means that $\lambda_k^x$ makes sense for all $x \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: thanks for the response! I actually meant 'applications' when I said areas/equations where those relations 'are found'. I have edited the post accordingly. I'm sorry about the ambiguity!